# I'm trying to change the mob's weapon if the player is near but it wont change

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

Everything seems fine as far as the command goes but the weapon of the enemy won't change.

```
execute at @e[type=minecraft:skeleton,name="Soldier"] if entity @a[distance=..5] run replaceitem entity @s weapon.mainhand minecraft:iron_sword 1
```

Comment: Optimisation tip: Give the skeleton a tag and later check for that, otherwise you replace the item 20 times per second when the player is near.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `as` not `at` to refer to the skeleton, `at` only changes the location of the command. Try `execute as @e[type=skeleton,name="Soldier"] at @s if entity @a[distance=..5] run (command)`

Comment: To be exact, you need both `as` and `at`. Your command is correct in that regard (didn't check if it works).